# lubuntu strange graphics

Tags: graphics, lubuntu, 14.10

I have just installed a fresh lubuntu 14.10. I have this graphics bug:

[image]

After this I installed the NVidia drivers, but nothing changed.
Then I installed the Intel drivers, still nothing.

I have both integrated and dedicated graphics card driver up-to-date now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is a graphics bug, I think the theme you're using is providing a texture that has a vertical gradient and it applies nicely to the taskbar but clearly not the notifications. I suggest trying another theme or editing this one.

Comment: Thanks, I used default theme in this screenshot, but changed the theme helped.